# Stata: Retrieve variable label in a macro

Tags: variables, stata, label

I'm generating graphs for several variables using a do-file, I would like to be able to retrieve a variable label (so that I could use it for the graph title).

In my dreams, something along those lines:

```
sysuse auto, replace
local pricelabel = varlab(price)
display "Label for price variable is `pricelabel'"
```

which would (in my dreams) yield:

```
Label for price variable is Price
```

I looked in the documentation of describe, summarize, as well as the part on labels, but could not seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the help files for extended functions of local/global macros: `help extended_fcn` (where `extended_function` is `variable label varname` [what you asked for] or `value label varname` [not what you asked for, but may be of use]). *E.g.*:

```
sysuse auto, clear
local x : variable label foreign
local y : value label foreign
di "`x'"
di "`y'"
```

returns

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. local x : variable label foreign

. local y : value label foreign

. di "`x'"
Car type

. di "`y'"
origin
```